# How does the MADS algorithm work in practice

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization

Mesh Adaptive Direct Search ([MASH](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2009/07/2352.pdf)) is an algorithm for [black box optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_optimization)

I want to understand an implement this method to solve some 2D multivariate blackbox function $f(x,y)$, but am having trouble understanding the algorithm.

**What I understand so far**:

1. Start with some initial trial value $x_0, y_0$
2. Create the 'Mesh'
3. Search a finite number of points on the mesh
4. If the search fails, perform a 'Poll' step $P_k = x_k + \Delta_k d$

**Where I am confused**

5. How do we 'create' the Mesh? How does the mesh change with each iteration?
6. How do we perform a search step? How do we choose which points on the mesh to search?
7. What does it mean to perform a poll step? How should $\Delta_k$ change? What is meant by $d$?

Thanks in advance for an help

Comment: Shouldn't it be Mesh Adaptive Direct Search (__MADS__)?